# получить имя цвета из hex кода или максимально близкое

Tags: python, matplotlib, color

Я знаю что из имени цвета, можно получить hex код.

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.colors.cnames["blue"])
```

А как получить наоборот имя цвета из hex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то с ходу готовое решение не нашёл, но можно попробовать перебором:

```py
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

colors = dict(mcolors.BASE_COLORS, **mcolors.CSS4_COLORS)
for color, rgb in colors.items():
    if rgb == '#800080':
        print(color)
# purple
```

Comment: ели б сходу нашел я, то не писал бы вопрос), за такой вариант спасибо, проблема в том что не все hex есть, надо подбират приближенное. Поэтому нашел решение и пытаюсь реализовать через webcolors и KDTree

Comment: если часто использовать, то можно инвертировать словаь ``colors_inv = {}``, 
``for color, rgb in colors.items():
    colors_inv[rgb] = color`` чтоб не перебирать каждый раз

Comment: @T800 "подбирать приближенное" это уже совсем другая задача

Comment: @T800 если вас интересует поиск ближайшего похожего цвета, то нужно об этом явно написать в тексте вопроса. А учитывая, что на вопрос в текущей его формулировке уже дан ответ — [вам лучше создать ещё один вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2948) с правильной формулировкой

Comment: @Эникейщик как это другая? вот у меня есть hex которого нет в словарях, ну надо тогда максимально близкое имя хотябы вывести

Comment: @T800 про «максимально близкое» в вопросе ничего не написано

Comment: @T800 а менять смысл вопроса после того, как на него уже дали ответ, не очень красиво

Comment: @andreymal я подправил название, но вот вам задача дайте точное имя такого hex - #f83e50 программным путем. Если дадите - сниму шляпу)

Comment: @T800 а отмечать галочкой ответ, который не отвечает на вопрос в текущей его формулировке, это вообще что-то максимально странное)

Comment: сначала дайте точное имя этого #f83e50 любым путем

Comment: @andreymal почему же? ведь в названии вопроса указано 'или'. А в развернутом виде не указан конкретный hex. Просто в процессе теста выяснилась загвоздка, где я уже в комментах описал.

Answer (score 5):

Нашел вариант решения такой

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from webcolors import (
    CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES,
    hex_to_rgb,
)

css3_db = CSS3_HEX_TO_NAMES
names = []
rgb_values = []
for color_hex, color_name in css3_db.items():
    names.append(color_name)
    rgb_values.append(hex_to_rgb(color_hex))
kdt_db = KDTree(rgb_values)
distance, index = kdt_db.query(colors[0])
print(f'closest match: {names[index]}')
```

Comment: Да, через поиск ближайших соседей - вполне себе решение.

Comment: Только лучше делать это не в rgb пространстве, а в каком нибудь Lab.  Там шкала вроде как ближе к человеческому восприятию различий цвета.